# About Maven resources

Tags: resources, maven

From the stand point of a Maven project, should files stored there be accessed in any special way or be treated as any other file where "resources" is just another directory?

What makes this directory special? Is it fair to say that "resource" is anything that is not a source file and that is used by a program?

I am a bit confused here. Please clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All files in the resources directory get added to your jar (or war) without being compiled.  Generally things like config files or other non-source resources are put in this directory, although as long as your files don't end in ".java" they could live in the sources directory and the resulting artifact would be the same.

To access a file in the resources directory you would use the ClassLoader.getResource or getResourceAsStream methods.

The other feature of resources when using Maven is that you can include property tokens that will be replaced by Maven as part of building your project.  For instance:

This line in a resource file

```
artifactName=${project.build.finalName}
```

Would be replaced with something like:

```
artifactName=my-project-1.0.0
```

Any of the properties available within Maven can be replaced in your resources.

Comment: Hmm ... in this case getResource() has nothing to do with the fact folder name is also "resource", is it?

Comment: @mac, no the folder name itself does not matter.  First of all, you can change the default resources directory to anything you want.  Also, accessing the files from that dir is done after the jar is built.  All of those files are placed relative to the root of the jar so the 'resources' directory itslef doesn't even exist anymore once your code is actually running.  Lastly, you can use `getResource` to get any file inside a jar.  So if you put an xml file inside one of your java packages in src/main/java you could get to it using the ClassLoader resource methods too.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a standard. By default, the contents of the resources directory are copied to the same target directory as the .class files and, if packaged as a jar, in the root of the jar.

You can also specify how resources are encoded. If you don't, you effectively preserve the encoding of the system on which you built, which is non-portable and is something Maven will warn you about.